# Boxplots equally spread out

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to spread my boxplots equally over the x-axis. The following code generates a figure where the two boxplots are close with plenty of space on either side. In generate I want the code to spread the boxplots out evenly regardless of the number of boxplots (in this example there are only two, but in general there will be many).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

statistic_dict = {0.40000000000000002: [0.36003616645322273, 0.40526649416305677, 0.46522159350924536], 0.20000000000000001: [0.11932912803730165, 0.23235825966896217, 0.12380728472472625]}

def draw_boxplot(y_values, x_values, edge_color, fill_color):
    bp = plt.boxplot(y_values, patch_artist=True, positions=x_values)
    for element in ['boxes', 'whiskers', 'fliers', 'medians', 'caps']:
        plt.setp(bp[element], color=edge_color)
    plt.xlabel("x label ")
    plt.ylabel("y label ")
    plt.title("Title")
    for patch in bp['boxes']:
        patch.set(facecolor=fill_color)


y_values = statistic_dict.values()
x_values = statistic_dict.keys()
draw_boxplot(y_values, x_values, "skyblue", "white")
plt.savefig('fileName.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxplot is not autoscaled after its creation. You may do that manually. Also adding some custom margin afterwards is possible.

```
plt.gca().autoscale()
plt.gca().margins(x=0.2)
```

Comment: plt.gca().autoscale() works!

plt.gca().margins(x=0.2) generates error, ValueError: more than two arguments were supplied

Comment: That would be because you are using an old version of matplotlib. I cannot give a valid solution for an older version.